# How to use ContinueWith with condition on existing Task<TResult>

Tags: c#, task

I'm trying to get some help on the `.ContinueWith()` method. 
I know something like this`Task<Task<bool>> t2 = nextTask.ContinueWith(t => T.FirstLevel("GG"));`

As you see below, this is a demo of what I was trying to do. My first level task returns a bool that will determine which task to continue with, also my second level task will return a bool to determine whether to go back execute the first level again or exit. This is where I'm stuck, I wouldn't want to make it recursive though.

Can anyone help?

I know one can use event handler to resolve this matter but the actual application code is really complex to change at this moment.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Continuewith
{
   class Program
   {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        tester();
        Console.ReadKey();
     }

    static async void tester()
    {
        TaskFunctions T = new TaskFunctions();
        List<string> p = new List<string>() { "111"};
        List<Task<bool>> CocurrentTasks = new List<Task<bool>>();
        foreach (string s in p)
        {
            CocurrentTasks.Add(T.FirstLevel(s));
        }
        while (CocurrentTasks.Count > 0)
        {
            Task<bool> nextTask = await Task.WhenAny(CocurrentTasks);
            if(await nextTask)
            {
               //do second level
            }
            else
            {
               //do first level
            }
            CocurrentTasks.Remove(nextTask);
        }
    }
}

class TaskFunctions
{
    public async Task<bool> FirstLevel(string gg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(gg);
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 10);
        await Task.Delay(500 * randomNumber); //other real useful Task Function will be in place to take up the time
        if (randomNumber > 5)
            return true;
        else
            return false;         
    }

    public async Task<bool> SecondLevel(string jj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(jj);
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 10);
        await Task.Delay(500 * randomNumber); //other real useful Task Function will be in place to take up the time
        if (randomNumber > 5)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
}
```

Here is my solution, not perfect but I can use it alright.

```
static async void tester()
    {
        TaskFunctions T = new TaskFunctions();
        List<string> p = new List<string>() { "111"};
        List<Task<bool>> CocurrentTasks = new List<Task<bool>>();
        foreach (string s in p)
        {
            CocurrentTasks.Add(T.FirstLevel(s));
        }
        while (CocurrentTasks.Count > 0)
        {
            Task<bool> nextTask = await Task.WhenAny(CocurrentTasks);
            if(await nextTask)
            {
               Task<Task<bool>> t2 = nextTask.ContinueWith(t => T.SecondLevel("GG"));
               if(!await t2.Unwarp())
               {
                  CocurrentTasks.Add(T.FirstLevel("111"));
               }
            }
            else
            {
               CocurrentTasks.Add(T.FirstLevel("111"));
            }
            CocurrentTasks.Remove(nextTask);
        }
    }
```

This, however, requires the first level task returns "111" so that the program will be execute that specific data again. "111" can be anything one can pass not just limited to a string.

Comment: Instead of passing string s to the task pass a class.  Any changes made to the class object in the task can be read by the main function.  The class can have lots of properties so you aren't restricted to only one Boolean like in your present code.

Comment: You should use `await`, not `ContinueWith`. What exactly is wrong with the code?

Comment: @Stephen Cleary It is not complete... I don't know how to let it execute first level when the second level return false

Comment: @jdweng yeah like a struct, but is that has anything to do with the question? BTW, I don't want to make those global.

Comment: *"I don't know how to let it execute first level when the second level return false"* Using `taskFunctions.FirstLevel("111");` doesn't work?

Comment: Yes.  You can add an ID number to the class (structures are obsolete) so you can identify each task uniquely.

Comment: why do you need separate Tasks to do this? maybe it would be easier to implement standard recursion and call it on one Task/Thread?

Comment: @slawekwin well the key point is that the first level tasks need to run parallel with each other and each task may return different result.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov then what happen next when the FirstLevel returns true? It needs to go on and execute the second level again.

Comment: then you could run multiple tasks in paralel (regardles of which level they are at the moment) in as many threads as you want, but you need result of first task to determine whether to run second anyway

Comment: @slawekwin can you may be write something out for me to see what you are saying exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need `FirstLevel` and `SecondLevel` to be separate `Task`s? Maybe it would be easier to control those calls as part of one, sequential `Task`? Basically, you would want to move code in your `while` to a method:

```
static async void tester()
{
    TaskFunctions T = new TaskFunctions();
    List<string> p = new List<string>() { "111" };
    List<Task> CocurrentTasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (string s in p)
    {
        CocurrentTasks.Add(CallConcurrentTasks(T, s));
    }
    while (CocurrentTasks.Count > 0)
    {
        var nextTask = await Task.WhenAny(CocurrentTasks);            
        CocurrentTasks.Remove(nextTask);
    }
}

static async Task CallConcurrentTasks(TaskFunctions t, string arg)
{
    do
    {
        if (await t.FirstLevel(arg))
        {
            if (!await T.SecondLevel("GG"))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    while (true);   //you should probably make some additional end condition here?
}
```

I hope I got the refacotring right. Alternatively you could use a thread-safe list for `ConcurrentTasks` collection and use your `while` code without any changes (collection passed as an argument to `CallConcurrentTasks` method).